# How to put a time value as a name for a column in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I am making a timetable in mysql and I want to put a column name as time, say, 3:00-3:45 and the values under these column would be varchar like maths or chemistry or whatever. But when I execute it, it shows an error.

```
mysql> create table timetable(Day varchar(20), 3:00-3:45 varchar(20), 4:00-4:45 varchar(20));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3:00-3:45 varchar(20), 4:00-4:45 varchar(20))' at line 1
```

Comment: Read this manual page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Escape the column name with backticks, but if you are placing time across columns, you might have a design problem with your table and/or database.

Comment: This seems like a bad design. Times should be values, not hard-coded as column names. Use columns `shift_start_time` and `shift_end_time`.